# pyplot distance between axis and plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a diagram to show everyday's data from a database. I made this diagram here for a specific day previously. I am not okay with something detail here which I don't know what keyword should I look for.

What I have is

[image]

But I want the diagram looks like (ignore the color and etc):

[image]

In my image, the time on x axis starts from whenever the first TimeStamp created (on the day the image shows was 8 a.m. but everyday starts from different time), but I want the hours always start from 7:00:00. That's the earliest time for TimeStamp to be created.

Second, I want to make some spaces between the edge of the plot and the first/last bar. I don't want bars to touch the edge of the plot.

Code I have is here.

```
import MySQLdb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# connect to MySQL database
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="r1", passwd="!r1db!",
db="r1array")
# prepare a cursor
cur = conn.cursor()

# this is the query we'll be making
query = """SELECT TimeStamp,Pac FROM SolarData WHERE DATE(`TimeStamp`) = CURDATE()-6 GROUP BY HOUR(TimeStamp);"""

# execute the query
cur.execute(query)
# retrieve the whole result set
data = cur.fetchall()

# close cursor and connection
cur.close()
conn.close()

# unpack data in TimeStamp (x axis) and Pac (y axis)
TimeStamp, Pac = zip(*data)

# graph code
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
plt.bar(TimeStamp, Pac, align='center', width=0.015)

# set title, X/Y labels
plt.title("PVIC R1 panel ")
plt.xlabel("Hour")
plt.ylabel("Pac")
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(20.5,10.5)
plt.grid(True)
plt.draw()
fig.savefig('test.png', dpi=100)
```

Comment: Your images did not come through (you don't have enough rep to post them your self, put them someplace public and a high-rep user can edit them in for you).  Please also include the code you used to generate the figure.

Comment: We are getting closer to a good question. If you can, remove the SQL statements and post a _minimal_ working example with sample data. This way we can reproduce the pictures in question.

Comment: Also have a look at `ax.margins` (or equivalently, `plt.margins`) if you want to avoid having things wind up on the edges of the plot.  In your specific case, if you didn't want to have the plot always start at a specific time, and just wanted the autoscaling to leave some room at the edges, `ax.margins(0.05, 0)` would add 5% padding along the x-direction and zero padding along the y-direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... I want the hours always start from 7:00:00 ... Second, I want to make some spaces between the edge of the plot and the first/last bar.

use [`plt.xlim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim) to set a start and end time. Here is an example with some toy data:

```
import datetime
import pylab as plt

# Some sample data
X = [datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 2, n) for n in xrange(9,13)]
Y = [4,8,3,2]

# Set the limits
start_time = datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 2, 7)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 2, 14)

plt.bar(X, Y, align='center',width=.015)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.xlim(start_time, end_time)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I get your point. Right now I don't know how to set the xlim range with TimeStamp format...which you know TimeStamp comes from MySQL, not a part of matplotlib or python.

Comment: As the diagram you generated, your 10 a.m. bar goes up to the top edge of the box. Is there anyway to get avoid of that? I mean, it will look nicer to make y axis up to 9 so that 10 a.m. bar won't touch the edge.

Comment: @ShuruiLiu That's easy, just set limits on the yaxis using `plt.ylim`. Or as Joe suggested in the comments, use `plt.margins` to give yourself a "gap" as you call it.

Comment: I think my question is: I need y axis to be autoscaled depends on the maximum value. So plt.ylim is not really a good choice here. plt.margins needs to set parameters like this `plt.margins(x,y)`. If I set y=0, the maximum bar will touch the top edge of the plot.